# pandas TimeStamp subtraction?

Tags: pandas

Why does the following code produce the same results?

Is there a way to subtract date from pandas TimeStamp?

```
print s['ADM.DT'] + pd.DateOffset(month=2)
print s['ADM.DT'] - pd.DateOffset(month=2)
```

s['ADM.DT'] is pandas.tslib.Timestamp object.

Comment: Is this because you are subtracting a negative offset so it becomes positive so same as first statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
pd.DateOffset(month=2)
```

It shifts the Date to the second month of the year. If you want to shift the date for 2 months you have to use:

```
pd.DateOffset(months=2)
```

Comment: But still the question remains why we do not move to a different year 02-2000 versus 02-2001.

Comment: If I use "months" the year changes the way I would expect it:
>>> nowpd
Timestamp('2014-10-20 11:36:07.810726')
>>> nowpd + pd.DateOffset(months=3)
Timestamp('2015-01-20 11:36:07.810726')

Comment: Depends what the OP is asking. For `month=2` it doesn't. But I guess OP is asking for `months=2`.